# Tomcat Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a spring mvc project, but it throws out `Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` when I run it by Tomcat. How to figure out which jar file has not been loaded correctly.
I have added `-verbose:class` to VM options, but it only prints out Loaded jar, not the error one.
Tomcat version: `apache-tomcat-8.5.23`
JDK version: `jdk1.8.0_152`
Spring version: `4.3.3.RELEASE`

The ERROR msg is below:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hello-world]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@c078b65]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4995)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@186802b8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Can you post logs from catalina.out? You can probably find out more details looking at the log file. Also, see this link [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Access_logging). It has more details on fine tuning your logging to understand more about what is causing this issue.

Comment: catalina.out is similar to this output log. I've used Luis's command to solve this problem.

Comment: additionally, this error could also occur due to zero kb jars in web-inf/lib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given you have access to a Bash terminal, you can try this one-liner to test your jars assuming they are all in the same directory

```
for j in $(find /path/to/lib -name '*.jar'); do jar -tvf $j > /dev/null 2>&1; [ "$?" -ne 0 ] && echo "$j jar is broken"; done
```

Result:

```
/path/to/lib/test.jar jar is broken
/path/to/lib/some.jar jar is broken
```

Comment: This command finds out a lot of broken jars，and I've exclude those from pom one by one. Thanks!

Comment: additionally, this error could also occur due to zero kb jars in web-inf/lib

Comment: Could you please tell me what is 'j' here, i cannot directly execute in windows cmd prompt ?

Comment: `j` is the iteration variable. You need a bash terminal to execute that, it's possible on windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is an older thread but I just ran into this issue. It turns out, if you package up your application using tar (rather than creating a war file) on Mac OS and then extract it on a Linux server, you'll end up with a "._libraryX.jar" for every "libraryX.jar". Unfortunately, because Tomcat tries to load every jar in your lib directory, it picks up these additional files which aren't jars at all. They contain extended file attribute data that Mac OS wants.

Have to create the tar file like this to keep those files out of your archive.

```
COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cvzf mytomcatapp.tgz mytomcatapp
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurres when your war file is damaged. Not only jar files but also other files in war file may be damaged. In my case, I found a damaged png file and after removing it, war file deployed successfully.
In order to find the damaged file use this command:

```
jar xvf yourApp.war
```

By running the command, name of each extracted file, will be printed and when it reaches to the damaged file, it prints the exception. So you can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

###### TLDR; Your JAR files might be corrupted, transfer them again.

---

In my case, I transfered a WAR file from a local machine to a server, and I couldn't managed to deploy my app. It turned out that some JAR files were corrupted. **The fix was only to transfer again my WAR to the server**.