# Tomcat 9.0.52 crashes with "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)" when started in debug mode - any work-around?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When trying to start Tomcat (9.0.52) in debug mode ("Debug on Server") from Eclipse (v2020-12 (4.18.0) / Build id: 20201210-1552) I get the following error (see full stacktrace further below):

```
16-Aug-2021 13:52:14.019 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@61322f9d]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        ...
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@61322f9d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

While the reasons seems clear - there is some issue reading a .jar file - the question I have is:
How can I find out, WHICH .jar is causing this issue? Is there some option to get more info on the root cause: which library (either from Tomcat or which application-jar?) that it tries to read is causing this?

The odd thing is: When I start this up in normal "run" mode in Eclipse or as a Windows Service, then Tomcat as well as the application start up fine. This zip-file problem only happens when I try to start it in debug mode! And - when starting Tomcat from Eclipse - then no .war-file is created but rather Tomcat's classpath is adjusted such, that the class files are used in-situ (i.e. directly from the target directory where they have been compiled to). So there is no additional .jar file created compared to the non-debug mode (which is why I am puzzled why this happens only in debug mode).

Eclipse uses Java 14 (if I am correct) but is configured to compile to 1.8 compatibility and the runtime (i.e. Tomcat and our application) uses Java 1.8 (I have installed the "almost latest" AdoptOpenJDK v1.8 / jdk-8.0.292.10-hotspot).

Tomcat's download page (https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) claims, that Tomcat 9.0.52 runs with Java "8 and later", so IMHO I should be OK in terms of prereq's.

Any idea how to get the above setup starting up/working in debug mode?

Full stacktrace:

```
...
16-Aug-2021 13:52:11.275 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1232] milliseconds
16-Aug-2021 13:52:11.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
16-Aug-2021 13:52:11.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
16-Aug-2021 13:52:11.866 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
16-Aug-2021 13:52:13.860 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,954] milliseconds.
16-Aug-2021 13:52:14.019 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@61322f9d]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@61322f9d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readNBytes(IOUtils.java:180)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readAllBytes(IOUtils.java:116)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:426)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
        ... 34 more
```

**Later addition:** I also tried the entire setup using a Java 11 VM for Tomcat but with the same result. So, this issue with some .jar-file having an invalid header or signature is apparently NOT a Java<=(1.)8 vs. Java >=v9 issue. So I reverted back to Java 1.8.

Comment: How to find broken jars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930734/2834978

Comment: Why don't you set an exception breakpoint and inspect the variables on the stack to find out which ZIP file it is trying to read?

Comment: In Eclipse it is sometimes useful to explore the `$CATALINA_BASE` folder it creates. By default it is in a subfolder of `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core` (relative to your workspace). Check if no libraries are missing or have strange sizes.

Comment: @meriton I don't know how to set such a breakpoint because the exception happens already before even reaching any of my code. I ran the startup with the `-verbose`-option which seems to indicate that the exception happens reading `rt.jar` (i.e. the basic java runtime which I have a hard time to believe - it just sounds too absurd). Still trying to find out more...

Comment: For future reference: The command line arguments for remote debugging contains a "suspend" option. If enabled, it will suspend program execution until a debugger connects (and has applied its breakpoints).

Comment: @meriton Thanks! Meanwhile I don't need to do any "remote debugging" since the issue - as I wrote - "just vanished". At the moment I only need to debug UI-handler code, so the normal debug mode is sufficient (and very convenient). If I had to set breakpoint in the server or application initialization code, then I would indeed need to use that remote debugging option to avoid being too late to set the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

A day later:
This morning when I tried to restart Tomcat again in debug mode to investigate further, the server started up! No more .zip-file issues! The problem just vanished... :-)

Thanks to all who responded!